# Flatter calls using promises: avoiding callbackception

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, promise, bluebird

I have found the following use case while working with promises. I am writing CoffeeScript for concision but the reading for JavaScript developers should be straight forwards

```
getUserName().then (userName) ->
  getRelatedCompany(userName).then (relatedCompany) ->
    registerConnexion(userName, relatedCompany)
```

In the above all request depend of the above results of the previous ones. What's the proper way to solve this to get something like this:

```
getUserName().then (userName) ->
  getRelatedCompany(userName)
.then (relatedCompany) ->
  # in that example, userName would be undefined here but there's less callbackception
  registerConnexion(userName, relatedCompany)
```

**EDIT**: I am using bluebird as promise library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use promises as proxies that represent values:

```
username = getUserName()
company = username.then(getRelatedCompany)
// assuming good promise lib, otherwise shim .spread of nest once
connexion = Promise.all([username, company]).spread(registerConnexion)
```

In bluebird, this is even simpler and becomes:

```
username = getUserName()
company = username.then(getRelatedCompany)
connexion = Promise.join(username, company, registerConnexion);
```

Since `.join` was designed for this use case in mind.

Comment: I am using bluebird as a promise library. I have edited your answer to fix a typo! Thanks!

Comment: @AsTeR editing to include a Bluebird answer, update soon.

Comment: I guess your StackExchange account description is a kind of rickroll... you got me ;) !